# multidimensional array (matrix) from single array as column

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering how can I assign a single vector as a specefic column/row in a dynamic multidimensional array in VBA.

I mean, if I run the following code:
    Dim m1() As Variant

```
ar1 = Array(1, 2)
ar2 = Array(4, 5)
ar3 = Array("a", "b")

m1 = Array(ar1, ar2, ar3)
```

I get something like this:

[image: (0 to 2), inside 3 arrays (0 to 1)]

m1 is a Variant (0 to 2), and in each cell I have an array of dimension 2 INSTEAD OF getting:

m1 as a variant(0 to 2, 0 to 1), in other words, a matrix, which I would get if I define the matrix as a variant(0 to 2, 0 to 1) and fill each cell separately.
Like this:

[image: (1 to 2, 1 to 2)]

I want to achieve something like:

```
m3 = [ar1;ar2;ar3]
```

but this throw

> Error 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind moving from 0 based to 1 based, and you don't have more than 65536 'rows', just add:

```
m1 = Application.Index(m1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Numeric array** : An array with a numeric index. Values are stored and accessed in linear fashion.

**Associative array** : An array with strings as index. This stores element values in association with key values rather than in a strict linear index order.

**Multidimensional array**: An array containing one or more arrays and values are accessed using multiple indices

**Numeric Array**

```
  <?php
     /* First method to create array. */
     $numbers = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

     foreach( $numbers as $value ) {
        echo "Value is $value <br />";
     }

     /* Second method to create array. */
     $numbers[0] = "one";
     $numbers[1] = "two";
     $numbers[2] = "three";
     $numbers[3] = "four";
     $numbers[4] = "five";

     foreach( $numbers as $value ) {
        echo "Value is $value <br />";
     }
  ?>
```

This will produce the following result −

Value is 1

Value is 2

Value is 3

Value is 4

Value is 5

Value is one

Value is two

Value is three

Value is four

Value is five

**Associative Arrays**

html>

```
  <?php
     /* First method to associate create array. */
     $salaries = array("jishan" => 2000, "bharat" => 1000, "abhi" => 500);

     echo "Salary of jishan is ". $salaries['jishan'] . "<br />";
     echo "Salary of bharat is ".  $salaries['bharat']. "<br />";
     echo "Salary of abhi is ".  $salaries['abhi']. "<br />";

     /* Second method to create array. */
     $salaries['jishan'] = "high";
     $salaries['bharat'] = "medium";
     $salaries['abhi'] = "low";

     echo "Salary of jishan is ". $salaries['jishan'] . "<br />";
     echo "Salary of bharat is ".  $salaries['bharat']. "<br />";
     echo "Salary of abhi is ".  $salaries['abhi']. "<br />";
  ?>
```

This will produce the following result −

Salary of jishan is 2000

Salary of bharat is 1000

Salary of abhi is 500

Salary of jishan is high

Salary of bharat is medium

Salary of abhi is low

**Multidimensional Arrays**

```
  <?php
     $marks = array( 
        "jishan" => array (
           "physics" => 35,
           "maths" => 30,   
           "chemistry" => 39
        ),

        "bharat" => array (
           "physics" => 30,
           "maths" => 32,
           "chemistry" => 29
        ),

        "abhi" => array (
           "physics" => 31,
           "maths" => 22,
           "chemistry" => 39
        )
     );

     /* Accessing multi-dimensional array values */
     echo "Marks for jishan in physics : " ;
     echo $marks['jishan']['physics'] . "<br />"; 

     echo "Marks for bharat in maths : ";
     echo $marks['bharat']['maths'] . "<br />"; 

     echo "Marks for abhi in chemistry : " ;
     echo $marks['abhi']['chemistry'] . "<br />"; 
  ?>
```

This will produce the following result −

Marks for jishan in physics : 35

Marks for bharat in maths : 32

Marks for abhi in chemistry : 39

Comment: None of that is VBA, so not terribly useful here.

Answer (score 0):

If im following, something like this

```
Sub MatrixTest()

ar1 = Array(1, 2)
ar2 = Array(3, 4)
ar3 = Array("a", "b")

a = Array(ar1, ar2, ar3)
a = Application.Transpose(a)

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost works. It changes the dimension but with transpose mutate the order of the cells. It works using (and following your example):
`a = Array (ar1, ar2, ar3) 
`a = Application.Transpose(a)`
`a = Application.Transpose(a)`